# What do we mean when we say Bose condensation? And why can't fermions condense if they don't pair?

Tags: condensed-matter, fermions, symmetry-breaking, bose-einstein-condensate

In common textbooks, we are told that bosons can condense in a single-particle state because of bose statistics and when the system undergoes a bose condensation, the bose field operator obtains a non-zero groundstate expectation value (GSEV). Apparently, this groundstate cannot be a particle conserved states otherwise the expectation value for the bose field operator must be zero. So is this non-zero field operator GSEV the main feature of [Bose condensation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_condensate)?

For fermions, we all know that unpaired fermions cannot condense because of Pauli exclusion principle. But it seems that the fermi field operator can also obtain a non-zero GSEV if the groundstate of some "strange" system is the superposition of zero fermion state and one fermion state (i.e. $|GS\rangle =\prod_{\alpha}u_{\alpha} |0\rangle_{\alpha}+v_{\alpha}|1\rangle_{\alpha}$, where $\alpha$ is the index for single-particle state.). This is weird to me. I have never seen such a situation in literature. Can this strange groundstate exist? And if it exists, does this non-zero GSEV imply some kind of condensation?

Comment: Maybe track down some articles on $He^3$ superfluidity? That's an example of Fermi-like particle condensation.

Comment: He3 superfluidity is an example of paired fermions that undergo condensation. In that case it is $c_{\alpha}c_{\beta}$ that obtains a non-zero GSEV but not $c_{\alpha}$. This paired case can be seen as some kind of bose condensation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The defining feature of a Bose condensate is that the one-body density matrix
$$ \rho^{(1)}(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}^{\prime}) =  \langle \Psi^{\dagger}(\mathbf{r})\Psi(\mathbf{r}^{\prime})\rangle,$$ 
has at least one eigenvalue that is macroscopically large, i.e. it is of order $N$, with $N$ the number of particles in the system. Here, $\Psi(\mathbf{r})$ is the field operator describing the particles in question. In fermionic systems, the corresponding condition is that the two-body density matrix
$$\rho^{(2)}_{s_1s_2s_3s_4}(\mathbf{r}_1,\mathbf{r}_2,\mathbf{r}_3,\mathbf{r}_4) =  \langle \Psi^{\dagger}_{s_1}(\mathbf{r}_1)\Psi^{\dagger}_{s_2}(\mathbf{r}_2)\Psi_{s_3}(\mathbf{r}_3)\Psi_{s_4}(\mathbf{r}_4)\rangle,$$ 
where $s$ indexes the spin variables, has at least one macroscopic eigenvalue.

In the vast majority of conceivable situations, including almost all experiments that have been ever performed$^{\ast}$, the number of particles is strictly conserved. It is therefore **fundamentally incorrect** to state that the field operator obtains a non-zero ground state expectation value (GSEV) in general. Assigning a non-zero GSEV to the field operator is just a useful calculational trick that leads rapidly to the observable physics. The drawback, of course, being that it also leads to all kinds of conceptual confusion. Therefore, although the presence of a non-zero GSEV implies some sort of condensation, the converse is definitely not true.

Usually, the term condensate is reserved for many-body systems in thermal equilibrium. The state posited by the OP would be forbidden by superselection rules in almost all conceivable fermion models. Furthermore, it is a few-particle pure state and therefore does not satisfy the normal criteria for a condensate.

---

$^{\ast}$ Recently people have begun to experiment with more exotic systems such as [photon condensates](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v468/n7323/abs/nature09567.html), where there is no superselection rule enforcing particle conservation.